# Presenting a specific view controller from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to present a view controller (a passcode request type view) every time my app becomes active. Once the correct passcode is entered, it should pop off the stack. The passcode view I'm trying to push isn't the initial view controller, so I'm having trouble accessing it from the AppDelegate's applicationDidBecomeActive.

I also tried pushing the passcode view from my MainViewController's ViewWillAppear, but it doesn't get called when the app becomes active; only when the screen is refreshed.

I've been researching similar problems across SO the past couple days, but I'm still not understanding the proper method. I've heard that I might not be able to push the view this way because the applicationDidBecomeActive may be called before the Storyboard or NavigationController is connected/initialized/etc.

If anyone could provide me with the correct way to push/present the view, or if there's somewhere else that'd be better to do this type of thing, I'd appreciate it.

**Solved**: I just deleted the view from storyboard and used a nib instead. I used:

```
PasscodeUnlockVC *passcodeUnlock = [[PasscodeUnlockVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PasscodeUnlockVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:passcodeUnlock animated:NO];
```

View hierarchy data:

```
(gdb) po [[(id)UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x736a4b0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7367b40>>
   | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x76977a0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer =     <CALayer: 0x769de60>>
   |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x7692110; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES;      autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x769a8c0>>
   |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x73868d0; frame = (0 64; 320 416); autoresize =  W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x75510e0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x76b93e0; frame = (0 0; 320 416); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7386850>>
   |    | <UINavigationBar: 0x73664b0; frame = (0 20; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque =  NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7366550>>
   |    |    | <UINavigationBarBackground: 0x7360ea0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7366520>> - (null)
   |    |    | <UINavigationItemView: 0x76b95e0; frame = (160 21; 0 0); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x76aa8e0>>
   |    |    | <UINavigationItemButtonView: 0x7550650; frame = (5 7; 73 30); opaque = NO;   userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7368b40>>
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `viewDidBecomeActive` message, and when I searched `developer.apple.com` for it, I got no results.  Perhaps you should tell us more about this method, or even show us your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant applicationDidBecomeActive. I'll edit the post.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your modal view showing up, but it's telling me pushViewController:animated is unrecognized, can you tell me if you tried this on iOS 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use `applicationWillEnterForeground:`, not `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, because it works better with multitasking gestures.  For example, you don't want to put up the lock screen if the user double-clicks the home button to display the task bar, and then dismisses the task bar without changing apps.

Presumably your `AppDelegate` has a `window` property, and you know that your window's root view controller is a `UINavigationController`.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    PasscodeViewController *pvc = [[PasscodeViewController alloc] init];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:pvc animated:NO];
    // [pvc release]; if not using ARC
}
```

Comment: I implemented that code without any warnings or errors, but instead of bringing up the entire view, it just shows the navigation bar with a black screen under it. Any ideas? I don't have to declare the view in the header or anything do it? Thanks again.

Comment: Pause in the debugger and do `po [[(id)UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.

Comment: Okay, I got the info back about the view hierarchy, but I'm not really sure how to parse/use it. Someone else on SO had the same problem with the black screen, and the solution was to delete the loadView implementation, which I don't have anyway.

Comment: Put the view hierarchy dump in your question so I can see it.

Comment: Well, I see a view in the dump (0x76b93e0) that presumably belongs to your `PasscodeViewController`.  You need to figure out why it's not set up correctly.  Does the view controller have a nib?  Is it named `PasscodeViewController.xib`?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
PasscodeViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"passcodeVCID"]; 
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
vc.mode = @"enable";
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Using in ***applicationWillEnterForeground*** method.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of Quick and generalised way:

```
getRootViewController().presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

func getRootViewController() -> UIViewController
{
    return (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController)!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is complete Solution in Swift 4
implement this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

 let isLogin = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Islogin")
    if isLogin{
        self.NextViewController(storybordid: "OtherViewController")


    }else{
        self.NextViewController(storybordid: "LoginViewController")

    }
}
```

write this Function any where inside Appdelegate.swift

```
  func NextViewController(storybordid:String)
{

    let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let exampleVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:storybordid )
   // self.present(exampleVC, animated: true)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = exampleVC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```