# How can I check and determine which view controller in storyboard is currently showing?

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

If the application was previously in the background, when `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called,how can I optionally refresh the user interface ?

I expect the current view controller is always the initial view controller in storyboard.I can't get the pointer to storyboard in my main `AppDelegate.m` .

How can I check and determine which view controller is currently showing ?

Comment: Does this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548911/presenting-a-specific-view-controller-from-appdelegate - i.e. use `applicationWillEnterForeground` in addition.

Comment: `AppDelegate` has a `window` property,but no storyboard.So what should I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a pointer to your storyboard then you can do this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [[[self window] rootViewController] storyboard];
```

where `rootViewController` is actually the initial view controller of your storyboard. If you expect this controller to be the current controller (as you say) then you're good to go, but if you want to actually update your UI, then I guess you could post a custom notification from the delegate (inside `applicationDidBecomeActive`), and register each controller that may be interested to catch it so it can update its UI  (or just add `self` as observer for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` to catch the same one that your delegate catches...).

PS. If your `rootViewController` is a `UINavigationController` you can get the currently showing controller like this:

```
id currentController = [[[self window] rootViewController] visibleViewController];
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's helpful. Yeah,I expect `rootViewController` to be the current controller , so I did `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` inside `applicationDidBecomeActive`.When I restart app ,`loginAciton` inside `rootViewController` still be called ,but could not `presentModalViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Navigation"]` . Why?

Comment: PS. My `rootViewController` is not a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Does it produce any errors? What is happening when you try to present the controller?

Comment: Hmm it's really difficult to tell what's wrong with so little information. Did you try to set a breakpoint and step to see why it's failing?

Comment: are you sure that your view controller is the view controller being presented, and you have nothing else being presented