# Load a specific viewController on push notification Swift 2 AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, appdelegate

I want to open a specific view controller (a hidden one, because it's only accessible when receiving a certain push notification (it's not accessible through the tab bar)) and I've been able to do this but I'm facing a problem..

My app has a custom Tab Bar controller called `RootViewController`. When you click on a notification with the special value it shows an alert view asking whether the user wants to open the notification or not.

The notification triggers bringing a specific view controller to the front but
the problem is that I don't have access to the tab bar anymore.

I don't know how to achieve this.

This is my code in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
var presentedVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
while (presentedVC!.navigationController != nil)  {
    presentedVC = presentedVC!.navigationController
}
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PushNotificationView") as? NotTestViewController

destinationViewController?.url = self.url!
presentedVC?.presentViewController(destinationViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

})
)
alertCtrl.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .Destructive, handler: nil))
```

This code works but not with the desired behaviour.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Thank you so much

**EDIT**

I've changed the `RAMTabBarAnimationController` to `TabBarController` because `RAMTabBarAnimationController` does not inherit from `TabBarController`. But I still see the same behaviour.

Comment: How about `presentedVC?.tabBarController?.selectedViewController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController!, animated: true)` ?

Comment: use window.rootViewController presentViewController.....please keep in mind ....apps that require Push Notifications to function, will be rejected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Presenting a specific view controller from AppDelegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548911/presenting-a-specific-view-controller-from-appdelegate)

Comment: Hi @anishparajuli the solution you mention is what I already have. I first instantiate the rootViewController `var presentedVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController` and the get the destination view controller `let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PushNotificationView") as? NotTestViewController` and finally what you mention `presentedVC?.selectedViewController!.presentViewController(destinationViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)` and it shows but the tabbar is below :/ (ps: my app works without notification) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to respond to my own question because I think maybe someone is facing the same situation, I have to say thanks to @Muneeba

Well, first of all you have to know if your remote push notification needs to do a background fetch, this is important because if so the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called twice (first when you click on the notification alert, seconds when it opens the app), so you have to be aware of this.

In my case I didn't do a background fetch, so my `content-available:false` flag was set to false.

Next thing to do is add you desire `["key":value]` to the notification payload to know whether you want to open a specific view controller or not.

**Manage whether open a view controller or not.**

In my app I want to open a alert control pop up always showing the body of the push notification (with a OK button) and only when certain value is set open a alert control with a question to the user whether or not he wants to open the new content that arrives (normally this content is a web based content that open a webview embedded in a view controller)

In the `didReceiveRemoteNotification`:

```
if let mensaje = userInfo["m"] as? String {
// Here is where I know if the value is set in the notification payload
 let alertCtrl = UIAlertController(title: titulo, message: mensaje as String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
 if url == nil {
   alertCtrl.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Destructive, handler: nil))
 } else {
 alertCtrl.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ver receta", style: .Default, handler: {
  action in

      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      //self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabbedController") as! UITabBarController
      let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("pushNotificationNavigation") as! UINavigationController
      let dVC:NotTestViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! NotTestViewController
      // This is for passing the URL to the view Controller
      dVC.url = self.url!
      self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: {})

      })
      )
      alertCtrl.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .Destructive, handler: nil))
   }
   // Find the presented VC...
   var presentedVC = self.window?.rootViewController
   while (presentedVC!.presentedViewController != nil)  {
      presentedVC = presentedVC!.presentedViewController
      }
      presentedVC!.presentViewController(alertCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)

      handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Nilesh the url that you're seeing is a variable of the NotTestViewController that I'm using. In the NotTestViewController I got a webView and it holds a url:String variable. When I am calling that controller from within the AppDelegate I am passing that url that came with the notification in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RAMAnimatedTabBarController` inherits which class? if it inherits `UIViewController`/`UITabbarController` then take a `UINavigationController` and set its `rootViewController` to  your `RAMAnimatedTabBarController` instance and then assign it as window's rootViewController and set the `navigationBar` hidden for this `UINavigationController` and when you want to push to specific Controller do like this

```
var presentedVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
presentedVC(yourdesiredController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I've changed the RAMAnimatedTabBarController to UITarbBarController because of what you said (the RAMAnimatedTabBar doesn't inherits from UITabBarController) after this change, I cannot manage to show the tabbar on above the new view.. also `Cannot call value of non-function type 'UINavigationController?` when trying to `presentedVC(destinationViewController!, animated: true)`

Comment: You want to show the tabs on your that specific view? tell me your complete requirements. Also update the question with new code.

Comment: Hi @Muneeba this is WebView that I only want to show when a notification comes with a specific payload, I want to show the tabbar because if not you cannot get rid of the webview also you cannot navigate through the app. This webview is only showing in the appdelegate in didReceiveRemoteNotification

Comment: Have u added the WebView in a UIViewController 's xib ?if so implement the solution i said. and before pushing make the navigationBar unhidden for that UINavigationController so now you will have the back option from WebView . and in viewDidDisappear of that controller don't forget to hide the navigationBar again.

Comment: Remove the while code block. presentedVC itself is a navigationController instance , there is no need to right presentedVC.navigationController.

Comment: I've removed the while code block and my WebView is a NIB file, I will implement what you have said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100145/discussion-between-neteot-and-muneeba).